# integrated way to take screenshot of a region and save it

Tags: windows, windows-11, screenshot

I ask this question because I believe there are lots of users interested in it:

I like the Windows + PrtScr combination that saves a screenshot of the entire screen on C:\Users<Username>\Pictures\Screenshot

However, my daily need for this function is just to save a region of the screen. My question is, is there a way that fine-tunes this option to make it ask the user to select a region and automatically save it in the Screenshot folder?

I am aware of Windows + Shift + S combination, but the problem is that it only goes into the clipboard and does not get saved automatically.

Also, I know there is a snipping tool of Windows that capture a screen region and save it with aid of GUI, but it is not automatic and too slow.

For my daily need, I need to make hundreds of screenshots and want to find to do it super fast without a third-party application.

I am using the latest update of Windows 11.

Comment: You can use Windows + Shift + S and just select the area. The screenshots are saved automatically in this location `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip` (W10). And the images remain even if you make multiple screenshots.

Comment: excelent. that was what I needed. tnx

Comment: @User552853 that sounds like it would be a good answer to the question.

Comment: @Mokubai - Somebody already did back in 2020. I think the existing answer deserves some attention instead.

Comment: @Ramhound good spot, thanks.

Comment: @Woeitg if the duplicate is not what you are after just give me a ping and I'll reopen.

Comment: @Mokubai - If it’s a keyboard shortcut it’s been asked about just a matter of finding it with the horrible search engine we have.

Comment: @Mokubai it is not exactly the same, but good enough for me... so I leave it as it